# No sound after installing Catalyst 11.4

Tags: 11.04, drivers, sound

I did a clean install of Ubuntu 11.04 and everything went fine.
The sound was working without a problem with the on-board device *Azalia (Intel HDA)* from the *ASUS Crosshair IV Formula* motherboard.

Then, i installed the proprietary drivers for the *AMD Radeon HD 6870* through this [guide](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Natty_Installation_Guide).
Now the sound is gone.

If i go to **Sound Preferences**, on the **Output** options i see two devices for sound output:

- *Internal Audio Analog Stereo* (selected)
- *Barts HDMI Audio [Radeon HD 6800 Series]*

Is there anything i can do?
If you need any more information, let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Same problem here. It's actually not after Catalyst install, but after first reboot. Can you confirm?
Also this question might be duplicate of that one: http://askubuntu.com/questions/36858/audio-not-outputing-throught-front-audio-connection

Comment: You are right @skfd! Both times the first reboot was to install the drivers, but they are completely unrelated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed it by adding `options snd-hda-intel model=generic` to the end of `/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf` and rebooting.

From: [Fix HDA Intel (Realtek ALC887) No Sound Issue In Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/11/fix-hda-intel-realtek-alc887-no-sound.html)